# Relative import issue while testing brownie

Tags: python, import, brownie

I am using brownie to interact with my Ethereum smart contracts. The **scripts** and **tests** are located in parallel **scripts/** and **test/** folders. How can I access the functions from **scripts/** in **test/** files?

[image]

Unfortunately relative imports do not work.

```
from ..scripts.helper import get_account
from ..scripts.deploy_fund_me import deploy_fund_me


def test_stake_and_withdraw():
    account = get_account()
    fund_me = deploy_fund_me()
    entry_fee = fund_me.getEntryFee()
    tx = fund_me.stake({"from": account, "value": entry_fee})
    tx.wait(1)
    assert (
        fund_me.fundsByStaker(account.address) == entry_fee
    ), f"{account.address}'s staking failed!"
```

The tests are run using the `brownie test` command from the **brownie_demo/** project's location. Using `from scripts.helper import get_account` does not work as well.

Answer (score 1):

Add a `__init__.py` file in your `scripts` folder.

[For reference on python modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15746675/how-to-write-a-python-module-package)